# Amazon Selling-Partner-API - How to update price and Quantity of the product

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-selling-partner-api

We wants to update the products attributes like quantity, price etc using the Selling Partner API.

We are referring following documents for the same.
https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/en-US/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuide.md#what-is-the-selling-partner-api

Which API we can use from the following list to update price and quantity
i.e from API list https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/tree/main/references
https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/tree/main/references

Selling Partner API for Pricing - In document Amazon have not mentioned about POST API
i.e to API to update price.
https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/references/product-pricing-api/productPricingV0.md

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you will have to use the feed api.
Create feed will require the proper type. If your intent is to only update price and quantities of existing listings, you can use the type POST_FLAT_FILE_PRICEANDQUANTITYONLY_UPDATE_DATA

The body of the request should be the equivalent of a manual price and quantity file submitted though amazon portal.
So it's like (please check yourself for more precise details):

sku | price | quantity

ITEM-SKU | itemprice | itemqty

with tabs in place of "|"
As i am just starting to develop this aspect (up to now i managed to implement order fulfillment tracking pushes and inventory download) this could very well be incorrect. Will update once i get deeper in the implementation of this

If you are totally new to the feed api take a look at https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/feeds-api-v2021-06-30-reference
The process is not that straight forward but it works in the end.

Hope this helps you

Edit: i tested a simple upload that changed one item price and quantity ad it worked fine. The actual implementation is not hard as long as the prerequisite knowledge / details are clear:

- general SP-api knowledg about token, roles, signing etc.
- feed submission workflow - explained here: https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/feeds-api-v2021-06-30-use-case-guide

Comment: Hi, Can you share your code which you used for testing please?

Comment: "The process is not that straight forward" -- understatement of the year. People don't realize how bad it is until they try updating produce prices through a modern GraphQL API like [Shopify](https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-sdks/efficient-way-to-update-prices-by-using-graph-ql/td-p/765049) (their REST API is even simpler to update prices).